# Where should I put new ListItem for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem, dropdown

I have a page with 1 main `DropDownList` and 2 other. Made it to choose settings for printing report.
The problem is - I use `DataSource`s in these `DropDownList`s but they haven't an empty value. Where should I put adding a new empty value into `DropDownList` for correct work?
There is my code (in a comment is a thing that i need to add)

```
protected void ddlMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (ddlMain.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "1":
            dFirst.Visible = true;
            dSecond.Visible = false;
            break;
        case "2":
            dFirst.Visible = false;
            dSecond.Visible = true;
            break;
}

<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMain" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnLoad="ddlMain_Load">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2 " Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>              
</div>

<div runat="server" id="dFirst" visible="false">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsFirst"
        DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" OnLoad="ddlFirst_Load">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsFirst" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conStr %>">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
//ddlFirst.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
```

I tried `OnLoad` secondary element, `OnLoad` main `DropDownList` and `Page_Load`. They don't fit me because new `ListItem` don't appears when page firstly loading or added more than 1 time when page refreshes.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question! Example is a comment In code-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Insert method in page load.

```
ddlAcademicYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --", "-1"));
```

0 is position at which you want to insert.

Comment: Thank you, but it works only with some Button_Click event but not in Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Add an `optionlabel` to your dropdownlist and assign the text "--Select--". Your dropdownlist should now have the desired default value.

Comment: Right inside of DropDownList tegs? I can't, because there I can put onli ListItems.

Comment: Try putting it after OnLoad of ddlFirst

Comment: Unfortunatly, doesn't help